# Solve the equation $y-3px+ayp^2=0$ where $p=\frac {dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation $y-3px+ayp^2=0$ where $p=\frac {dy}{dx}$

My Attempt:
Given
$$y-3px+ayp^2=0$$
$$3px=y+ayp^2$$
$$x=\frac {1}{3} \cdot \frac {y}{p} + \frac {a}{3} \cdot yp$$
This is solvable for x. Differentiating both sides with respect to $y$
$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {1}{3} \cdot \frac {p-y\frac {dp}{dy}}{p^2} + \frac {a}{3} (y\cdot \frac {dp}{dy} +p)$$
$$\frac {dx}{dy} = \frac {1}{3p} - \frac {y}{3p^2} \cdot \frac {dp}{dy} + \frac {ay}{3} \cdot \frac {dp}{dy} + \frac {ap}{3}$$
$$\frac {1}{p} - \frac {1}{3p} -\frac {ap}{3} = \frac {y}{3} \cdot \frac {dp}{dy}\cdot \frac {ap^2-1}{p^2}$$
$$\frac {3-1-ap^2}{3p} = \frac {y}{3} \cdot \frac {ap^2-1}{p^2} \cdot \frac {dp}{dy}$$
$$(2-ap^2) = \frac {y}{p} \cdot (ap^2-1) \cdot \frac {dp}{dy}$$
$$\frac {dy}{y} = \frac {ap^2-1}{p(2-ap^2)} dp$$

How do I integrate the RHS of above equation?

Comment: This method won't let you solve it, because even after integrating, you'll still end up with an expression containing $y$ and $p$, just another form of your question

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua So how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

$$\frac{ap^2-1}{p(2-ap^2)} = -\frac{1-ap^2}{p(2-ap^2)} =  - \frac{(2-ap^2) - 1}{p(2-ap^2)} =  - \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p(2-ap^2)}$$

**Hint 2:** The second expression involves two simple logarithmic expressions and can be and explicitly calculated.

Answer (score 1):

From @Rebellos work $$\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int \frac{dp}{p}+\int \frac{dp}{p(2-ap^2)}$$
In the third integral let $p=1/t \implies -dt/t^2$, then $2t^2-a=u$, we get
$$\ln y= \ln p-\frac{1}{4}\ln u \implies y(p)=\frac{Cp\sqrt{p}}{(2-ap^2)^{1/4}}~~~~(1)$$
Inserting this in the given ODE, we get
$$x(p)=\frac{y+ayp^2}{3p}~~~~(2)$$
Eqs.(1) and (2) define parametric equation of  family of curves when $p$ acts like a parametre, $C$ is the arbitrary constant of integration for a fixed value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving for $p$ we get

$$
y' = \frac{3x\pm\sqrt{9x^2-4ay^2}}{2ay}
$$

or

$$
2ay y'=3x\pm\sqrt{9x^2-4ay^2}
$$

now calling $u = a y^2$ we have

$$
u' = 3x\pm\sqrt{(3x)^2-4u}
$$

and now following with $z = (3x)^2-4u$ we arrive at

$$
z'\pm 4\sqrt{z}=6x
$$